Is there a way to make an svg circular progress bar using stroke dasharray?
I have been trying to recreate this progress bar, but I have been stuck to the step where I can implement the dashes between the line. If you have any ideas it would be great.

This is what i have accomplished so far.

I have used react-move library to animate the clock
<CircularProgressbar
  value={value}
  text={`${roundedValue}%`}
  circleRatio={0.75}
  styles={buildStyles({
    rotation: 1 / 2 + 1 / 8,
    strokeLinecap: "butt",
    trailColor: "#eee",
  })}
/>


Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/OJPqXbe

You can use circles (as in this example) or paths with stroke-dasharray and combine that with a mask.


document.forms.form01.meter.addEventListener('change', e => {
  document.querySelector('#m3 circle')
    .setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', `${parseInt(e.target.value) + 1} 120`);
  document.querySelector('#gauge')
    .setAttribute('transform', `rotate(${parseInt(e.target.value) * 3})`);
  document.querySelector('#text').innerHTML = `${e.target.value}%`;
});
body {
  background-color: #191919;
  display: flex;
}
<form name="form01">
  <input type="range" name="meter" min="0" max="90" value="15" step="1">
</form>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
  <filter id="blur1">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation=".2" />
  </filter>
  <filter id="shadow2">
      <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="0" stdDeviation=".6" flood-color="#4ebcc4" />
    </filter>
    <mask id="m1">
      <circle r="40" stroke="white" stroke-width="50"
        fill="none" stroke-dasharray="91 30" pathLength="120" />
    </mask>
    <mask id="m3">
      <circle r="40" stroke="white" stroke-width="30"
        fill="none" stroke-dasharray="15 120" pathLength="120" />
    </mask>
    <mask id="m2">
      <circle r="14" stroke="white" stroke-width="6"
        fill="none" pathLength="120" />
     <circle r="14" transform="scale(.9) translate(2 0)" stroke="black" stroke-width="6"
       fill="none" pathLength="120" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(50 50) rotate(135)"  mask="url(#m1)" filter="url(#blur1)">
    <circle r="46" stroke="#4ebcc4" stroke-width="1.5"
      fill="none" stroke-dasharray=".6 14.4" pathLength="120" />
    <circle r="40" stroke="#005a96" stroke-width="7"
      fill="none" stroke-dasharray="1 1" pathLength="120" />
      
    <circle r="40" stroke="#235e6b" stroke-width="7" mask="url(#m3)"
      fill="none" stroke-dasharray="1 1" pathLength="120" />
      
    <circle r="33" stroke="#4ebcc4" stroke-width="2"
      fill="none" pathLength="120" />
    <circle r="30" stroke="#4ebcc4" stroke-width="5"
      fill="none" stroke-dasharray=".5 14.6" pathLength="120" />
    <circle r="14" mask="url(#m2)" stroke="#4ebcc4" stroke-width="6"
     fill="none" pathLength="120" />
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(50 50)" filter="url(#blur1)">
    <circle r="24" stroke="#4ebcc4" stroke-width="3"
      fill="none" stroke-dasharray=".1 2.9" pathLength="120" />
    <text id="text" font-size="10" font-family="sans-serif"
      fill="#4ebcc4" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle"
      dominant-baseline="middle" filter="url(#shadow2)">15%</text>
    <g id="gauge" transform="rotate(45)">
      <path transform="rotate(-135) translate(0 -15)"
        d="M -2.5 0 A 1 1 0 0 0 2.5 0 L 0 -6 L -2.5 0" fill="#4ebcc4" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>



